# How to calculate into how many parts network will be divided

Tags: ip

Hi so i have a network `11.0.0.0/16` and a mask `255.255.248.0 (21 bits)`. My question is into how many part this mask will divide my network? I know the answer is 32, but i dont know how to calculate it. Maybe someone would help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mask - 255.255.248.0 is "subnet" mask. Look at your network adress and this little number after "/" - that number tells how many bits You have in your network(not subnetwork) mask. If we have this knowledge, we can find how many bits we have to describe our sub-networks. It's simple:

Our adress space is 16 bits long. So we can use 11.0.X.X, yep? And then, we decided to split our whole network to subnetworks. And we created submask which is 21 bits long. Now, just substract no. of mask bits(16) from submask bits(21). We've got 5. And how many diffrent values 5 bits can hold? `2^5 = 32`. Voila.